# How good is support for createMediaElementSource() in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, web-audio-api

I am having a difficult time finding information about createMediaElementSource() support. The mozilla MDN shows support starting with version 6.0 but caniuse.com states that safari apparently does not support it.

So what is true? Does safari support this function? If yes, starting from which version?

Comment: I couldn't find it on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=createMediaElementSource)

Comment: @Xotic750 go to http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api and click on "known issues"

Comment: Funny thing is, another developer on stackoverflow told me safari supports it. So many contradicting sources.

Comment: I would suggest trying it yourself, https://www.browserling.com/ only seems to have upto v5.1 available but there may be other free services out there that have v6 that you could try. Maybe saucelabs.com (open source developer account, if they still do it)

Comment: Just checked on my account and they have v5 to v9 available.

Comment: Just tried running http://mdn.github.io/media-source-buffer/ on v6 and got error https://saucelabs.com/beta/tests/ce404aec24f64c4085966a21f79e4cde/watch On v7 it didn't run at all.

Comment: @Xotic750 what about 8-9? This is pretty weird, considering it has been 4 years now since the functions release.

Comment: v8 also got an error https://saucelabs.com/beta/tests/70b74b29230240649c83e8fe07f2e6c5

Comment: v9 was also an error https://saucelabs.com/beta/tests/3e04031bbf114e0bbc9dc0dcb1dc6a4f/watch

Comment: It did work for me in FireFox, Chromium and Google Chrome, latest versions

Comment: @Xotic750 that is really unfortunate. The function is so great. I might have to fallback to normal XMLhttprequests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran the MDN test http://mdn.github.io/media-source-buffer/ on all versions of Safari available to me on saucelabs (v6 to v9) and it did not work on any of those versions.

Comment: Also thank you for letting me know of that website where you can do the testing.